# XMLHttpRequest can not load. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: c#, jquery, web-services, api, cors

I have read many similar problems in StackOverflow, but the solutions don't work for me.
I can use it using Postman (Chrome extension). I am passing data as 'Header'. And I get 200 return code.

[image]

I need to call this method using ajax Jquery :

```
$.ajax(apiUri, {
   beforeSend: function (xhr, settings) {
       xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + $('#AccessToken').val());
   },
   dataType: 'text',
   cache: false,
   success: function (data) {
       console.log(data);
       $('#output').text(data);
   }
});
```

But in this case, I got an error.

Like [image: console error using jquery/Ajax]

At Resource server side I have set in web.config.

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Comment: I found the solution for same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I just put in global setting

```
    protected void Application_BeginRequest()
    {
        if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            Response.Flush();
        }
    }
```

and did some changes in web.config(system.webserver) settings

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

then working fine :)

Thanks

Comment: This fixed my error, but now getting another error. Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent. First, this error is thrown and then the request is successfully completed and returns data.